# Using a reference to create a new object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I think that this is a pure Python "problem" but some context is needed:

I'm creating a simple Python script to modify ods documents with the library [ezodf](https://pythonhosted.org/ezodf/).
Ods files are similar to Excel documents: a table containing cells that contain value, format, etc.
The source comes from a template that I can't edit since I don't have the access to it and I need new cells with the same format as the ones I have but creating them with ezodf is not an option.

---

Let's work just with column "A" to simplify

I want cell["A5"] to be a copy of cell["A3"] but if I do
`cell["A5"] = cell["A3"]`
the cell "A3" ***moves*** to "A5" instead of filling cell "A5" with a copy and I can no longer access "A3"

My question is, what can I do to assign a cell["A5"] to a copy of "A3" instead of assigning it to "A3"?

Comment: Check out the python [copy module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy). In this case you could just write `cell["A5"] = copy.copy(cell["A3"])`. (or use `deepcopy`, depending on your use case)

Comment: Seems library-specific to me because depending on the design of the object in "cell" this can work but this library was designed differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Maksymilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13855521/maksymilian-mika) for showing me [this module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy), I've tryied with `cell["A5"] = copy.deepcopy(cell["A3"])` to create new cells based on the original "A3" cell and it works like a charm